# Grok patterns logstach custom

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

hello im trying to get grok patern of this :

```
2589522 HARS-X6790  2022-08-05 08:55:15 --EX: SCR45778554 ID '346402454540629' 

%{NUMBER:ligne} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog_timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}
```

Result :

{

"ligne": "6790",

"syslog_timestamp": "2019-08-05 08:55:15",

"syslog_message": "--EX: SCR 45778554 ID '346402454540629'"

}

i need to add this **HARS-X6790** to the grok ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `DATA`

```
%{NUMBER:ligne} %{DATA:stuff} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:syslog_timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}
```

You can check what `DATA` captures [here](https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns) or [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/main/patterns/legacy/grok-patterns)